# How to stop creating extra instances when using google managed vms?

Tags: deployment, docker, cloud, google-compute-engine, gcloud

Every time I deploy to Google's Managed VM service, the console automatically creates a duplicated instance. I am up to 15 instances running in parallel. I even tried using the command:

```
gcloud preview app deploy "...\app.yaml" --set-default
```

I tried doing some research and it looks like even [deleting these duplicated instances can be a pain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28883900/how-to-permanently-delete-google-managed-vms). Thoughts on how to stop this duplication?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can deploy over the same version each time:

```
gcloud preview app deploy "...\app.yaml" --set-default --version=version-name
```

This will stop creating VMs.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a shot. Do you know how to delete the instances? I've tried through the console, shell, and the another user's [recommendation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28883900/how-to-permanently-delete-google-managed-vms) with no luck.

Comment: Hm...I just tried and was able to successfully delete a GCE instance created by deploying a GAE MVM after I deleted the GAE instance associated with it. Have you deleted the instances under "App Engine > Versions" first? I know the way AppEngine MVMs are handled is a little buggy right now. (Sorry for the alphabet soup of acronyms!)

Comment: That did it! deleting the versions ("App Engine > Versions") and then the instances ("Compute Engine > VM Instances") stops them from being spun up again! Appreciate the help. Great solutions!

Comment: how to delete the version which is set as default version?