# google app engine how to control the number of instance nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, app.yaml

I am using google app engine with nodejs.
I want to limit the number of instances used by app engine. 
I have tried app.yaml before deploying with gcloud cli but I think it doesn't work...
I have set app.yaml file like following

```
runtime: nodejs
vm: true
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 3
  cool_down_period_sec: 120 # default value
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.7
```

But its using 8 instances still at this moment.
How can I decrease the number of instances and control them?

After running `gcloud app versions list` ,

```
SERVICE  VERSION          TRAFFIC_SPLIT  LAST_DEPLOYED              SERVING_STATUS
default  20160811t015921  0.00           2016-08-11T02:03:24+09:00  SERVING
default  20160811t022251  0.00           2016-08-11T02:26:20+09:00  SERVING
default  20160811t023404  0.00           2016-08-11T02:36:45+09:00  STOPPED
default  20160811t031525  0.00           2016-08-11T03:17:48+09:00  STOPPED
default  20160811t053241  0.00           2016-08-11T05:35:19+09:00  STOPPED
default  20160817t191913  0.00           2016-08-17T19:21:46+09:00  STOPPED
default  20160817t220352  0.00           2016-08-17T22:06:17+09:00  STOPPED
default  20160818t171126  0.00           2016-08-18T17:14:07+09:00  STOPPED
default  20160820t000714  0.00           2016-08-20T00:10:16+09:00  STOPPED
default  20160820t033731  0.00           2016-08-20T03:39:45+09:00  STOPPED
default  20160821t023159  0.00           2016-08-21T02:34:05+09:00  STOPPED
default  20160821t025235  1.00           2016-08-21T02:55:13+09:00  SERVING
```

And after running `gcloud app instances list`,

```
SERVICE  VERSION          ID  VM_STATUS  DEBUG_MODE
default  20160811t015921  0   RUNNING
default  20160811t015921  1   RUNNING
default  20160811t022251  0   RUNNING
default  20160811t022251  1   RUNNING
default  20160811t022251  2   RUNNING
default  20160811t022251  3   RUNNING
default  20160811t022251  4   RUNNING
default  20160821t025235  0   RUNNING    YES
```

comes out.

Comment: Hey - I'm on the App Engine team.  Can you run a few commands for me? `gcloud app versions list` ... then `gcloud app instances list`

Comment: I am guessing you have deployed multiple versions of your app, and each of them are creating new instances.  But it's just a guess :)

Comment: I have added more details and edited the question. thank you for helping @JustinBeckwith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the output of your commands, it looks like you have multiple versions of your application running.  Each version will spin up (n) instances based on load, *even if they're not receiving traffic*.

It looks like version `20160821t025235` is the one you want to keep running.  Try doing this:

```
gcloud app versions stop 20160811t015921 20160811t022251
```

If you do that, it should stop the other versions.

Answer (score 1):

It's a known GAE issue, you may want to star it: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12363.

A few workarounds are suggested in the thread or in the links from the thread.

One of them leads to an answer which appears to be a good way of eliminating the need for manually stopping and deleting the undesired instances: [How to stop creating extra instances when using google managed vms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31484826/how-to-stop-creating-extra-instances-when-using-google-managed-vms)

Comment: thank you ~ so this means for now, that I have to stop instances one by one which exceeds my max limit?

Comment: yes for the ones already created. See my updated answer for a way to avoid that down the road.